# What are the equation linking static air temperature with true airspeed & altitude?

Tags: airspeed, temperature

If I want to calculate static air temperature (OAT), but I'm only given an altitude and a true airspeed. Is there such an equation that relates these principles together. I've had a look at wikipedia and to calculate OAT, the total air temperature is required. Problem is, I don't have a Mach number to solve the equation. Is there another way to solve this problem

Comment: And to know the Mach # you need the static air temperature... a circle of doom question I'd say...

Comment: You don't have calibrated airspeed? How do you get true airspeed without the calibrated airspeed?

Comment: OAT and pressure altitude (PA) lets you compute density, from which you can relate calibrated airspeed (CAS) and true airspeed (TAS). So if you know any three of OAT, PA, CAS, and TAS, you can get the forth. Right now you are short a piece of information in order to "close the loop" and get OAT. Note: I am assuming you are at a slow speed and can ignore Mach number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided that your calculations take place for a standard day, below 11 km altitude the Outside Air Temperature is simply a linear function of altitude. From the [wikipedia article for Standard Atmosphere:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Atmosphere)

[image]

So OAT = 15 - 1.98 * Altitude, with OAT in °C and Altitude in 1,000 ft. Airspeed data is superfluous.

Comment: With a big emphasis on standard (average) day, with delta ISA being zero.